# What is T-star packing

Tags: parameterized-complexity

What is a T-star packing and what is Proper Maximal 3-Star Packing?
I read some definitions and can't understand

"By a T-star we mean a complete bipartite graph K1,t for some t ≤ T. For an undirected
graph G, a T-star packing is a collection of node-disjoint T-stars in G."

Comment: What in particular is confusing here?

Answer (score 1):

So a $t$-[star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(graph_theory)) is the graph you get by taking one central node and connecting $t$ neighbors to it. Equivalently, a $t$-star is the complete bipartite graph $K_{1,t}$ if you wish to express it like that as your definition does.

A *$t$-star packing* then is a bunch of such $t$-stars found from some graph $G$ so that their nodes don't overlap. As a simple example, consider the 4-cycle. You can find a 1-star packing of size 2 in it: take one edge as the other 1-star, and the other edge as the other 1-star.

The packing described above is *maximal*: you can't extend it by adding a new member  (i.e., a third 1-star) into it. It also happens to be *maximum*, i.e., it is the largest such packing you can find. I encourage you to think about what the difference between a *maximal* and *maximum* packing is, i.e., find an example where they differ.

I don't what *proper* here means, but it is likely defined in your source.